# preventDefault not working correctly Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to get my form to give an alert and prevent save if it meets a certain criteria (the if statement) and save if anything else but if I stick `preventDefault` inside the IF it still allows me to save.

I have tried putting it outside the IF but then no matter what I can't save the form and my `formContext.data.save()` doesn't work.

```js
function denyCreateVariationSor(executionContext)
{
    debugger;

    var id = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("gilm_variation").getValue()[0].id;
    
    var url = 'gilmartins-test.crm11.dynamics.com/.../gilm_variations eq ' + id + ')';
    var variationStatus;
    
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
    fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data =>
    {
        var arr = data.value;
        variationStatus = arr[0]["gilm_variationstatus"];

        if (variationStatus != 870110000)
        {
            executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
            alert("You can't add a SOR onto a completed/cancelled variation");
        }
        else
        {
            formContext.data.save()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `fetch` request is _asynchronous_, you can not cancel the event from within the callback. You'll need to implement this using `await` or something, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: The actual problem at hand aside, I'd put this check into a Business Rule and have it run on entity level to prevent bulk/backend changes as well.